Elastic how to properly reindex a data stream, and keep the data stream name?
I am new to Elastic so I am not very experienced with reindexing data streams.
I need to reindex a specific index in a data stream. I do not want to have to create a new data stream and use that data stream going forward. I want to use the same data stream.
I am reindexing because there are mapping conflicts in this specific index data stream.
I have read this documentation. The problem is when I try to reindex with that process, it creates an index just fine with the mapping fields removed I don't want.
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": ".ds-metrics-generic-default-2024.11.08-000012"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": ".ds-metrics-generic-default-2024.11.25-000014"
    "op_type": "create"
  }
}

However, if I list all data stream indexes, for metrics-* .ds-metrics-generic-default-2024.11.25-000014 is not listed
GET _cat/indices/metrics-*?v&s=index:desc

I can only assume this is because it's a data stream and data streams are particular about how their indexes are created. Is this a problem? Why is this new reindexed data not in the data stream? Does it need to be for it to be usable?
What is the proper way to reindex .ds-metrics-generic-default-2024.11.08-000012 to keep the same data stream name, and make sure its data is a part of the metrics-* data stream?
I think I would need to create a new data stream, reindex ALL indexes to it, delete the old data stream, recreate, and reindex all data back. That process sounds time consuming, error prone, and messy.
I have read suggestions that I should "just use aliases" But it's not clear to me how I would do that. Can someone specifically detail a process I can follow for all this?
